# how can I add csv files for zend translate in ini file

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation, zend-translate

I have translate.tr, translate.en, translate.fr files under 
application/config directory. I used to

```
  $translate  = new Zend_Translate('csv', '../application/configs/translate.tr', 'tr');
  $writer     = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('../docs/translate.txt');
  $logger     = new Zend_Log($writer);
  $translate->setOptions(array( 'log' => $logger, 'logUntranslated' => true ));

  $translate->addTranslation('../application/configs/translate.en', 'en');
  $translate->addTranslation('../application/configs/translate.fr', 'fr');
```

Now I want application.ini file to deal with initialization. So

```
resources.translate.registry_key            = "Zend_Translate"
resources.translate.adapter                 = "csv"
resources.translate.options.logUntranslated = true
resources.translate.options.scan            = "directory"
resources.translate.options.disableNotices  = 1
;resources.translate.options.logfile        = APPLICATION_PATH "../docs/translate.txt"
resources.translate.data                    = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/languages"
resources.translate.locale                  = "tr" ; default language
```

Now I think I need to show zend to know where these csv files resides. How can I show it?

Comment: Do you mean CVS or CSV ? Please correct your title.

Comment: do you know what is "concurrent version system" and "comma separated values"?

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Translate setup is well documented in the manual.

The `application.ini` settings are just the same which you should pass as an options to the object in array format.

Take a look at the `Translate` resource source code in `Zend` directory.